# Ignore safety check when using setnames

Tags: r, data.table

```
DT<-data.table(a=1,b=2,a=3)
DT
#   a b a
#1: 1 2 3
setnames(DT,"b","c")
#Error in setnames(DT, "b", "c") : 
# 'old' is character but there are duplicate column names: a
```

In the example above, you can see that I wish to change the header of a column that is not duplicated, but `setnames` prevents me from doing so. Is there a way to ignore the check, as the column header I am changing is not duplicated?

Comment: Use the numeric position (2) rather than the name ("b")?

Comment: Well I do not know what position the name "b" is. To use the numeric position, I would have to grep("b",DT,fixed=TRUE) and that would not be very efficient.

Comment: I probably would have used `match` rather than `grep`, but still. I agree its an extra step, but I doubt there are serious performance consequences. Perhaps one of the more data.table savvy folks will weigh in on whether this behavior is something that ought to be modified. But as it is, I don't see a way around it.

Comment: I agree with @joran here. `grep("b",DT,fixed=TRUE)` shouldn't be too much of performance overhead. If anything, it's just not recommended way of programming, otherwise it's perfectly legitimate way.

Comment: Alright, then I will do just that for now but leave the question open for others. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

+1 Now fixed in v1.8.11. From [NEWS](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/NEWS?view=markup&root=datatable) :

> setnames(DT,"oldname","newname") no longer complains about duplicated
>   column names in DT so long as oldname is unique and unambiguous.
>   Thanks to Wet Feet for highlighting.

Answer (score 4):

You could strip out some of the logic in the `setnames` call and iron it down to this:

```
set_names <- function(x, old, new) {
  i <- match(old, names(x))
  new <- new[ !is.na(i) ]
  i <- i[ !is.na(i) ]
  invisible(.Call(data.table:::Csetcharvec, attr(x, "names"), as.integer(i), new))
}

DT <- data.table(a=1,b=2,a=3)
set_names(DT, "b", "c")
DT
```

gives me

```
> DT
   a c a
1: 1 2 3
```

Note that it only changes the first name encountered in the case of duplicates. That said, it's not recommended to `.Call` unexported code like this, and you should probably test and ensure this doesn't break in your use cases.